# Present duplicates I answered to

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, search

Many, many questions already have been asked. But instead of closing them as duplicate they often get answered.

Very often I catch myself too answering off the top of my head instead of searching the duplicate, because it is much faster.

But maybe we can make the search for duplicates better.
It would be great if I could check a checkmark in the closing-as-duplicate dialog that, when enabled, searches only for my questions or questions I answered to.

It is much easier to remember a question that I came around in the past and deciding if it is the duplicate. And since many users tend to answer questions in the same area, it is much more probable that relevant questions are shown.

Comment: Or you could type `user:me keywords...` in the search box in a new tab.

Comment: Sure. I can do many things manually. A system is ment to automate things for us.

Comment: Not important enough to warrant developer time, given that the feature is already available in search. [Some duplication is actually desirable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243035/show-related-questions-immediately-after-posting (show related questions immediately to help users find duplicates)

Comment: BTW: We are way beyond *some* duplication on SO.

Comment: [143K user answering blatantly trivial, obvious and absolutely basic C++ question instead of looking for duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673304/what-is-the-difference-between-include-bits-stdc-h-and-include-bits-stdc).

Answer (score 1):

> Very often I catch myself too answering off the top of my head instead of searching the duplicate, because it is much faster.

that's probably because either you already answered or you already saw similar answers. The fact that you can answer very quickly is a good indication that the question already has an answer.

Whereas it's tolerated for unexperienced users, with your rep, you probably have a gold badge in the topics you're answering to, so you could quickly:

- google for a duplicate (rewording the question if needed) appending with "site:stackoverflow.com", find it, navigate, copy link, hammer. Done
- if you don't find an exact dupe like this, you can still close with an approximate dupe, then use the "edit" feature to change by a more accurate one in the next minutes (that is if you want to lock the question because you *know* it's a duplicate)
- if you know you already answered, click on your profile (prefills the "user:me" part and search for keywords. Even if the search engine is bad, searching through your posts with your terms often gives the answer.

Sometimes the question is worded in a complete different way, and the duplicate is a good way to reach/unearth the original question, so it's okay that it stays, as [Jeff Artwood stated](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) (and sometimes you cannot be aware of all the duplicates, even with a gold badge)

If you're infuriated at users who got upvoted on a blatant dupe (annoying as hell, true), or worse, some gold badge owner reopens the question so he can answer & get upvotes (I have names :)),and this behaviour persists with a particular user, flag for moderation.

And in the end, if everyone provides good arguments that this isn't a dupe, and you finally agree, you can always reopen & answer. Noone will slap you for that.

Comment: If a user is **blatantly** abusing their hammer privileges - SOCVR is *not* the place to try and get the community to right a wrong by targeting votes on related posts for the purposes of deleting them. Instead - raise your suspicions including evidence in a custom flag.

Comment: @JonClements agreed, but in the case I'm hinting at, I saw this guy reopening twice against _my_ closures. Not 20 times, so I cannot know if the guy does that for a living (I'lve edited)

Comment: What I'm saying (and not hinting at) is that the room won't want to be involved and nor will it with such targeting so you shouldn't even be mentioning it as an option.

Comment: I'm trusting your judgement (even if the facts are different...) edited out.

Answer (score -2):

I find this topic very interesting,(more details below), but are we barking up the right tree?

The way I see it the best ways to gain rep, for those who put their score above the effectiveness of the site as a whole, is to produce dupes or near dupes.

Restated: By policy we say no dupes but the system actually rewards better for dupes.

Note: those who don't put their score above the effectiveness of the site will post questions because they need answers and will answer questions because there is a need, regardless  of the impact on their "score"

So the below points are stabs at a few adjustments which may help to make gaming the system much less rewarding.

### Reasoning:

I rarely if ever find the need to ask questions, (and slightly less rarely a need to answer). There's already so much here that I really don't need to ask many new questions, & answers I might give aren't usually really an improvement over answers already given.

The above fact, however, is detrimental to my reputation score, which is pretty low considering how often I use the site.

Here's the most interesting part (to me @ least):
If I did care more about my reputation score, the best way for me to get a better score would be to find a popular, fairly straight forward question and tweak it a little, make my own post, then watch the answers pour in. As [Jeff Atwood pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243035/show-related-questions-immediately-after-posting) in the article Robert Harvey linked in comments, this isn't necessarily bad. In theory, this will help more users more easily find an answer to their questions.

So, given that the above is true, we can fight duplicates indefinitely because the system rewards them. Alternately I suspect tweaking the reputation system might be more effective than the more brute force methods we are used to.

### Some Thoughts:

- -Programmatically decrease point rewards for questions that share a high percentage of text with an older, already answered, & well
  traveled/upvoted answer.
- -Revist the duplicate finding algorithm (possibly add a second which checks after the question has been written but before it gets
  posted... could likely make it the same check that assigns reward
  value)
- -Provide higher rewards for questions that are unique (both for upvotes on the question as well as the answer... because answering
  obscure questions, theoretically, provides a wider breadth of answers
  & topics... because we really don't need 1000s of questions on
  javascript closures [not saying we have that many but once a topic
  has been beat to death but always gets answers we are more likely to
  get duplicates... because it's easier to ask than to read all the
  answers to all the variations of the same question])
- -Decrease rewards for users who's reputation score increases past 1K for questions asked... we don't need to motivate these people to ask
  questions, we need to motivate new users who just don't feel as
  comfortable asking... these people will ask regardless (but with
  generally lower/attainable seeming scores new users may be less
  likely to attempt to game the system)
- -Decrease rewards as scores get higher anyway, this might tend to decrease the desire to quickly answer simple questions (without
  researching if they are answering something that's already been
  answered)

Sorry I think this stuff through too much :D. I would, however, be interested in hearing other peoples thoughts.

Comment: +1 for the effort but -1 for being completely off-topic...

Comment: Hey vba4all ok.
So now that we've established that it could be considered off topic for this question/proposal; please suggest a better place to suggest alternate solutions to avoiding duplicates than a proposed solution for better duplicate avoidance. Thanks

Comment: I suppose I should expect downvotes, and I generally would if this were in standard stackoverflow. However this is meta stackoverflow, I really expected more of a collaborative effort & more open forum for fixing problems. However I now see that it is not: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late
However little my opinion matters (very little is obvious) I recommend re-thinking the 'rules' a little @ least for meta if no where else.
One last thought, would any of the downvoters have marked my 'answer' as a dupe if I had posted it as a question?

Comment: So given that I'm well over 1k I shouldn't ask more questions? How would that positively affect new users who have absolutely no idea who am I? This is not only off-topic, it is a mix of weird thoughts.

Comment: Hi @Camilo Terevinto your comment makes it obvious that I left out some essential common ground in this answer.  I am suggesting that there are some who are more interested in gaining reputation than in making the site more effective. Decreasing rewards for those with higher rep is one part of an approach that is designed to make gaming the system to gain higher rep less rewarding. I mention this because intentionally creating a dupe to quickly gain rep would become less effective & appealing IF the reward for creating new questions steadily decreased.